# How do late events affect joins?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have been reading up a bit about Google DataFlow. I am interested in using it for a join operation between two streams I receive. Both streams contain a shared ID which can be used as the join key.

However, in some cases the events from Stream B might be received in the system later then the events in stream A. In this case, after my given watermark, assuming I set something like `.withAllowedLateness(3 days)`, how would DataFlow handle this?

Would it reload the old events to match to them? Would it not be able to join these? Would it keep 3 days of data in memory in-case some late event comes? (if so would it miss joins if I restart the operation because for example I changed the window size?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events will be persistently buffered using Dataflow's state mechanisms (not necessarily in memory) up to the allowed lateness, and then garbage-collected.

Under the hood, items will be grouped by the `(key, window)` tuple, so if you change windowing and [update the pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline#changing-windowing), then I believe some join results may be missed, because an older buffered item from stream `A` will have a different `(key, window)` tuple than a newer item from stream `B` with the same key, due to the difference in `window`.

You can experiment with this in unit tests in the Beam direct runner using [TestStream](https://beam.incubator.apache.org/blog/2016/10/20/test-stream.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know how large of windows can be supported this way? What costs will large windows incur?

Comment: By "costs" I mostly mean resources.

Comment: We've seen jobs run successfully while buffering up to a few hundred megabytes of data per key. It might work with more, too, but I believe data for one key has to fit in memory (even though it's not stored there constantly).

Comment: Wouldn't the issue not be the "per key" storage, but rather the overall storage for all keys required to match joins on a large window?

Comment: The overall storage is also concern regarding disk space, but only per-key buffered data gets loaded in memory. Things are grouped by key first and foremost, and only after that, within a particular key, by window (since windows themselves can be different between different keys - e.g. session windows).

Comment: So the keys are used as partitions if I understand you correctly. Thanks for the help.